# VB.NET: Abort FormClosing()

Tags: vb.net, formclosing

I have a code snippet that I want to run when the app is closing. So, I used `FormCLosing` event. But now i wanna place a confirmation message for exiting. Like, if the user clicks the Exit(`X`) button, there'll be a prompt, if he clicks NO, then the app will not close and revert to previous state.

Now I find that hard to achieve using `FormClosing` event. because it'll get executed no matter what button the user clicks. 
Any remedy for that?

I mean, I need an even like `ExitButtonPressed()`..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try something like

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If (MessageBox.Show("Close?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Have a look at

[FormClosingEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx)

And

[CancelEventArgs.Cancel Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx)

> The event can be canceled by setting
>   the Cancel property to true.

Comment: Inside the FormClosing event.

Comment: Thanx. but having another problem now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256909/vb-net-messagebox-with-yesnocancel-no-cancel-triggers-same-event

Answer (score 0):

'Button2 and closebutton of the form both  closes the form asking the same 'question

Dim button2Yes As Boolean = False
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

```
    If MessageBox.Show("    Sure to close?   ", "CLOSING CONTROL", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        button2Yes = True
        Me.Close()
    Else
        button2Yes = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If Not button2Yes Then
        If Not MessageBox.Show("    Sure to close?   ", "CLOSING CONTROL", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```