# Confirming program close with a messagebox

Tags: vb.net

I have a message box that pops up when i press a close button that basicaly says" Are you sure you want to quit" but when i click the no button or cancel but the program closes any how

this is my code:

```
'Close Button
Private Sub BtnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnClose.Click

    Dim result = MessageBox.Show(" Are you sure you want to quit", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You never tested the result

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET: MessageBox with YesNoCancel - No & Cancel triggers same event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256909/vb-net-messagebox-with-yesnocancel-no-cancel-triggers-same-event)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing nothing with the value of `result`. You need to inspect the value and determine whether you call Me.Close(). Code approximately

```
If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
    Me.Close()
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using then message box to prevent accidental form close, your approach may not work always. The message box will not be shown if the user closes the application in any other way than clicking the "Close" button.

Try using the FormClosing event.

```
'Close Button
Private Sub BtnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

'FormClosing Event
Private Sub MyForm_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show(" Are you sure you want to quit", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) <> DialogResult.Yes
         e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You issue `Me.Close()` no matter what the `result` is. Check the result and execute `Me.Close()` only the user clicks `Yes`

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to quit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2, "Close application") = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
    Me.Close()
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy this:

```
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show(" Are you sure you want to end the Application", "School Management System", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim result = MessageBox.Show(" Are you sure you want to quit", "System Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Me.Close()

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a child form, it opens as a result of a button in a main form:

```
If MessageBox.Show(" Are you sure you want to exit the application ? ", "Exit  ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then

 Me.Hide() : MainForm.Show()

        Else
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
```

Comment: Please reformat your code so that it's all inside the code block, and so that it's indented properly. See [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
Dim closingfrm = MsgBox(" Are you sure to close", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
If closingfrm = DialogResult.Yes Then
Application.Exit()
End If
```