# Add a cancel button to input box VB

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I have made a simple calculator and I would like to know if you put in a string instead of a double and if you press close or not. The program is a simple calculator where the menu is a box with buttons for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. I would like it if you enter a string a messagebox pops up that tells you to enter a number and when you enter an empty message or click cancel it takes you back to the start of the program. Here is the code

```
Public Class CalcForm
    Property num1 As Double = Nothing
    Property num2 As Double = Nothing
    Private Sub CalcForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
    Private Sub Addition_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Addition.Click
        Getnum()
        Dim Answer As Double = num1 + num2
        MessageBox.Show("The answer is " & Answer, "Answer")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Subtraction_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Subtraction.Click
        Getnum()
        Dim Answer As Double = num1 - num2
        MessageBox.Show("The answer is " & Answer, "Answer")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Multiplication_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Multiplication.Click
        Getnum()
        Dim Answer As Double = num1 * num2
        MessageBox.Show("The answer is " & Answer, "Answer")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Division_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Division.Click
        Getnum()
        Dim Answer As Double = num1 / num2
        MessageBox.Show("The answer is " & Answer, "Answer")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Getnum()
        num1 = InputBox("Enter your first number", "Number 1")
        num2 = InputBox("Enter your second number", "Number 2")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also I don't care about the difference between an empty ok or a cancel. But since I use doubles do I have to make it a string then convert to an double? If I do, how do I detect if the string has letters and ask the user to re-enter their number?

Comment: The answer can be found here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256909/messagebox-with-yesnocancel-no-cancel-triggers-same-event][1]

Comment: Stop using InputBox, start using TextBox.

Comment: regarding the string validation, you can simply use isNumeric function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need your message box?

If you follow Hans Passant's recommendations and start using TextBox, you could simply bind your variable properties and parse and format them.

Have a look at the example below, it is more lines of code but gets you an opportunity to look at binding parsing and formatting.

It is a simple form with your four buttons and 3 text boxes. User cannot "get out" of the TextBox value is not numeric. Should you go for this solution, I would recommend to set the TextBox property for the result to ReadOnly :)

```
Imports System.Math
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub

Private _num1 As Double
Property num1 As Double
    Get
        Return _num1
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If (value <> _num1) Then
            _num1 = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("num1")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
Private _num2 As Double
Property num2 As Double
    Get
        Return _num2
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If (value <> _num2) Then
            _num2 = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("num2")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
Private _Answer As Double
Property Answer As Double
    Get
        Return _Answer
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If (value <> _Answer) Then
            _Answer = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Answer")
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub CalcForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' TextBox for result
    TextBox3.ReadOnly = True
    Set_bindings()
End Sub
Private Sub Addition_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Addition.Click
    Answer = num1 + num2
End Sub
Private Sub Substraction_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Substraction.Click
    Answer = num1 - num2
End Sub
Private Sub Multiplication_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Multiplication.Click
    Answer = num1 * num2
End Sub
Private Sub Division_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Division.Click
   Answer = num1 / num2
End Sub

Private Sub Set_bindings()
    Dim binH As Binding
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Clear()
    binH = New Binding("Text", Me, "num1", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    AddHandler binH.Parse, AddressOf NumParser
    AddHandler binH.Format, AddressOf NumFormatter
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(binH)
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Clear()
    binH = New Binding("Text", Me, "num2", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    AddHandler binH.Parse, AddressOf NumParser
    AddHandler binH.Format, AddressOf NumFormatter
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(binH)
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Clear()
    binH = New Binding("Text", Me, "Answer", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never)
    AddHandler binH.Parse, AddressOf NumParser
    AddHandler binH.Format, AddressOf NumFormatter
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add(binH)
End Sub

Private Sub NumParser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ConvertEventArgs)
   If IsNumeric(e.Value) Then
       e.Value = e.Value
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub NumFormatter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ConvertEventArgs)
    e.Value = FormatNum(e.Value)
End Sub

Private Function FormatNum(ByVal x As Double) As String
    Dim sFormat As String
    sFormat = ""
    Select Case Abs(x)
        Case 1 To 1000
            sFormat = "##0.000"
        Case Is > 10000
            sFormat = "0.000E+00"
        Case Is = 0
            sFormat = "#0.0"
        Case Is < 0.001
            sFormat = "0.000E-00"
        Case Is < 1
            sFormat = "#0.0000"
    End Select
    FormatNum = Format(x, sFormat)
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Yeah, I was a real noob when I made this. Since then, I've never used inputboxes again. Thanks for the help.