# MesageBox Show only accepts two arguments, but I need a third argument

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework

I need to have a confirmation dialog box by showing MessageBox.Show("Caption", "Title", MessageBoxDialog), but an error occurred "Error 1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' accepts this number of arguments"

Already tried to check some other codes in the internet, but its always with the same error.

This was copied from dotnetperls.com

```
`   Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Is Dot Net Perls awesome?", "Important Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)`
```

and this one is currently in my code, copied from [MessageBox with YesNoCancel - No & Cancel triggers same event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256909/messagebox-with-yesnocancel-no-cancel-triggers-same-event)

```
 `Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
    If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        MessageBox.Show("No pressed")
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        MessageBox.Show("Yes pressed")
    End If`
```

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Comment: I suspect that you have a class in your project named `MessageBox`.  That will take precedence over types with the same name in referenced assemblies.  Either change that name or qualifying the other type in your code.

Comment: I'd suggest using a `Select Case` in that code.  It will be more succinct than `If...ElseIf`.

Comment: Try using it like this `System.Windows.Forms.MessqgeBox.Show()`

Comment: if you want another argument, you've come to the right place =)

Comment: also, remove the   `.show`  just `msgbox("1","2",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)`

Comment: @EssKay No, that won't compile. You are mixing Apples and Oranges.

Comment: @Mary thanks stalker :) Seems my memory was off and you were correct. My answer should reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variant 1

```
Dim result = MsgBox("Message" , MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Caption")
Select Case result
    Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
      MsgBox("Yes pressed")   
    Case MsgBoxResult.No
      MsgBox("No pressed")   
    Case MsgBoxResult.Cancel
      MsgBox("Cancel pressed")   
End Select
```

Variant 2

```
Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Message", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
    MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")    
ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
    MessageBox.Show("No pressed")    
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Yes pressed")    
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

From my previous code which I thought I lost:

`If confirm = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    Dim reConfirm As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("YOU ARE REALLY SURE?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If reConfirm = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    End If
End If`