# Can we code on mesaage box buttons in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

**I want to code on message box buttons in vb.net. It should perform a specific task of my choice when clicked**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MessageBox with YesNoCancel - No & Cancel triggers same event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256909/messagebox-with-yesnocancel-no-cancel-triggers-same-event)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [`DialogResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult) to perform specific code for the different buttons available on the [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox). See the following example:

```
Dim dlgResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Your Message", "Your Caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

If dlgResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
  'Code on Yes
ElseIf dlgResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
  'Code on No
End If
```